# s-arc transitive graph is also (s-1)-arc transitive

Tags: graph-theory

I read on a paper that an s-arc transitive graph is also (s-1)-arc transitive and thus (s-2)-transitive, which was stated as obvious. However, I was thinking that a path of 2 edges, $P_2$, is 2-arc transitive but not vertex-transitive, right?

Could anyone advise me where I got it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly even Chris Godsil and Gordon Royle got this wrong in their book "Algebraic Graph Theory". They write: "If $s\ge 1$, then it is both obvious and easy to prove that an $s$-arc transitive graph is also $(s-1)$-arc transitive.". So, no wonder this misconception spread.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. For example, $2$-arc transitivity does not imply $1$-arc transitivity. Consider the star picture, the so called $K_{1,n}$ graph. Just let $n=5$. It is 2-arc transitive but not arc-transitive.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you have it wrong. The claim is only true under extra conditions. The simplest that comes to mind is that there are no vertices of degree one.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is that the s-arc transitive graph must also be regular (all vertices have the same degree). with this extra condition it is easy to prove the claim. Note in some trivial cases the result can be concluded by resorting to trivial LOGICAL rules.